# Pandas left join gives NaN

Tags: python, pandas

#### DataFrameA

```
                                 RunId  isClean  isFinished
0                 APAC_P1_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         1.0
0                      APAC_P1_REGTEST      1.0         1.0
0                APAC_P2a_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                     APAC_P2a_REGTEST      0.0         1.0
0                APAC_P2b_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                     APAC_P2b_REGTEST      1.0         1.0
0                APAC_P2c_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                     APAC_P2c_REGTEST      0.0         1.0
0                APAC_P3a_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                     APAC_P3a_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                APAC_P3b_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                     APAC_P3b_REGTEST      0.0         0.0
0                      Cliquet_REGTEST      0.0         1.0
```

#### DataFrameB

```
                             RunId  Status
0            APAC_P2a_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
2            APAC_P2b_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
4            APAC_P2c_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
6            APAC_P3a_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
8            APAC_P3b_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
10             CS_P10_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
12             CS_P11_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
14              CS_P1_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
16              CS_P2_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
18              CS_P3_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
20              CS_P4_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
22              CS_P5_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
24              CS_P6_HSFR_REGTEST   Error
```

#### DataFrameA.join(DataFrameB,on='RunId',how='left',rsuffix='_y')

```
                                 RunId  isClean  isFinished RunId_y Status
0                 APAC_P1_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         1.0     NaN    NaN
0                      APAC_P1_REGTEST      1.0         1.0     NaN    NaN
0                APAC_P2a_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                     APAC_P2a_REGTEST      0.0         1.0     NaN    NaN
0                APAC_P2b_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                     APAC_P2b_REGTEST      1.0         1.0     NaN    NaN
0                APAC_P2c_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                     APAC_P2c_REGTEST      0.0         1.0     NaN    NaN
0                APAC_P3a_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                     APAC_P3a_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                APAC_P3b_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                     APAC_P3b_REGTEST      0.0         0.0     NaN    NaN
0                      Cliquet_REGTEST      0.0         1.0     NaN    NaN
```

A question, why all `NaNs` ? There are nonNaN intersections like `APAC_P2a_HSFR_REGTEST`. Sorry if it's a dumb question, but googling did not helped.

Comment: you could use merge easily for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) working with `index`, so need create index by `RunId` column:

```
df = DataFrameA.join(DataFrameB.set_index('RunId'),on='RunId',how='left',rsuffix='_y')
```

Or use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = DataFrameA.merge(DataFrameB,on='RunId',how='left')

print (df)
                    RunId  isClean  isFinished Status
0    APAC_P1_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         1.0    NaN
1         APAC_P1_REGTEST      1.0         1.0    NaN
2   APAC_P2a_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0  Error
3        APAC_P2a_REGTEST      0.0         1.0    NaN
4   APAC_P2b_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0  Error
5        APAC_P2b_REGTEST      1.0         1.0    NaN
6   APAC_P2c_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0  Error
7        APAC_P2c_REGTEST      0.0         1.0    NaN
8   APAC_P3a_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0  Error
9        APAC_P3a_REGTEST      0.0         0.0    NaN
10  APAC_P3b_HSFR_REGTEST      0.0         0.0  Error
11       APAC_P3b_REGTEST      0.0         0.0    NaN
12        Cliquet_REGTEST      0.0         1.0    NaN
```